# C# - Remove an Element from an Array using Delegates

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm kind of lost here as I do not know how to proceed. Here's what I got so far:

```
//T[] tab initialised earlier with T elements)

public bool Delete(T element)
            {
                var find = Array.FindIndex(tab, x => x.CompareTo(element) == 0); 
                if (find == -1) // if item not found then don't do anything
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    tab.Remove(element); // can't use Remove with
                        return true;
                }

            }
```

Given Error:

Error   1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Remove' and no extension method 'Remove' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found

Comment: since I can't use Remove with T[] Arrays. Why?

Comment: An array has a fixed length, and you can't actually remove from it. One thing you can do is overwrite the existing element with "nothing". But that will leave a "hole" in the array. Like this: `tab[find] = default(T);` Depending on what `T` is you can also use `null` or `new T()`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you cannot remove `element` out of `tab` because `tab` is declared as *array `[]`* which does not support `Remove` method, if possible, declare `tab` as `List<T>`, so you are able to call `Remove` from `List<T>`